# Iterate over custom list setting and return all entries

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex

If I have a Salesforce custom list setting, 'Info_List__c' with 1 field, 'Info_Field__c'.

What would a method look like that would iterate through the list and return all entries.

And how would I call that method from a VF page and store the results in a JS object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller

```
global with sharing class Ctrl{
@RemoteAction
global static List<String> getList(){
  List<String> result = new List<String>();
  List<Info_List__c> lst = [Select Info_Field__c from Info_List__c];
  for(Info_List__c lstObj : lst){
    result.add(lstObj.Info_Field__c);
  }
  return result;
}
}
```

And in JS side

```
var strArr = Ctrl.getList();
```

If you have namespace it would be (e.g. NS)

```
var strArr = NS.Ctrl.getList();
```

Comment: Unexpected token : List. For List<Info_List__c>... Any ideas?

Comment: change list variable name to lst (fixed it)

Comment: Cheers Moti! Much appreciated!

Comment: I changed the JS call to just var strArr = '{!List}'. Works perfectly.